# The best and/or fastest to learn Java API for consuming XML feeds with attributes

Tags: java, xml

What is the best and/or fastest to learn Java API for consuming XML feeds like this:

```
<body copyright="Company">
    <student id="1" fname="Anthony" lname="Hopkins"/>
    <student id="2" fname="John" lname="Anderson"/>
    <student id="3" fname="Will" lname="Smitherman"/>
</body>
```

As you can see it provides all the data with attributes. Also, XML Feed data  will be accessed using URLs with parameters specified in the query string.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Voted to close...no one can tell you how to learn something.  Just write the code and you'll learn.

Comment: I am not asking how to learn, I am asking for a suggestion what to learn in this particular case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to use JaxB to generate the Java classes for you. If you have a schema you use xjb tool that will create the classes and can let java do all the parsing without you needing to do anything.

Look at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2006/jw-0626-jaxb.html

Comment: The easiest IF you have a schema.  There are tools which can generate a schema from sample XML data.

Comment: Yes true. If the XML Dima posted is the actuall XML then you can always produce a schema. :)

Comment: The problem with JAXB is that schema is not provided

Comment: This is very simplified example, the real thing is more complicated

Comment: @Dima - you can generate a Schema from a XML/XSLT tool such as Stylus Studio.  Mind you, you should really be designing your schemas up front (or ask your 3rd party provider of your XML data to do so)

Comment: You do not need an XML schema to use JAXB.  You can start with POJOs.  For more information check out my blog:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with it but XStream might be the easiest way to import data from XML.  This can produce a data structure to match your data.

Comment: JAXB is easier to use than XStream:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-does-jaxb-compare-to-xstream.html